# Display jquery dialog in parent window

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a website, that uses an iframe. The iframe itself is the content of the website. Now in the iframe I would like to use the jQuery Dialog. However when using it, the overlay and dialog is only displayed inside the iframe not on the parent. My parent html has the following html defined for the dialog:

```
<div id="modalHolder"></div>
```

In my iframe I am using the following javascript to create the dialog and to show it.

```
dlg1 = $(window.parent.document.getElementById("modalHolder"));
dlg1 = dlg1.dialog({
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    overlay: 
    {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        opacity: 0.65
    },
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

To show the dialog I use this:

```
dlg1.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dialog function is running within the context of the iframe, it will always create the dialog divs (like the semi transparent background div and the dialog div) as children of the iframe's . Even though you're grabbing the element from the parent document, the actual script is still running in the iframe. If you have Firefox and Firebug, you should be able to use the HTML inspector to see what's going on.

I can only think of two solutions:

1. Use a modified version of the jQuery dialog library. I do not recommend this at all
2. Move your JavaScript so that it executes within the context of the parent document.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to move the dialog divs from the iframe to the parent document after they are created, but it would be really ugly. Something like.. #('.ui-widget-overlay, ui-dialog').appendTo(window.parent.document.body);

Comment: You are right. It looks it moves the "modalHolder" from the parent into the iframe. I will move my js from the child to parent. I was trying to avoid that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I could move the elements to the parent, however they height/width would need to be recalculated.

Comment: 3) - Use jQuery defined in the parent context, per Dmitry.

Answer (score 27):

There is simple and graceful solution:

1. Include jquery and jqueryui into your parent window
2. After this you can access to the parent JQuery object within iframe

For example:

```
var $jParent = window.parent.jQuery.noConflict();
var dlg1 = $jParent('#modalHolder');
dlg1.dialog();
```

Comment: that made my life suddenly much easier.

Comment: +1, but I would upvote much more if I could! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I found after doing this that jQuery in the parent window no longer worked when referenced as `$` . To fix that, I just removed `.noConflict()` from the code above.

Comment: Whenn I tried this console says  $jParent is undefined ? I have included jquery in parent window

Comment: Wow this saved my career. It's not always in window.parent.