# Display jquery dialog in parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

I want to use jQuery Dialog to display popup through an iframe. However when using it, the overlay and dialog is only displayed inside the iframe not on the parent. 
I have checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958946/display-jquery-dialog-in-parent-window) but that solution will work if I have access to the code of parent page that contains my iframe but in my scenario I don't have access to the pages that will use my page as iframe. How can I display Dialog in parent page?

Comment: Is it cross domain or what?

Comment: You cannot fortunately modify pages wich is not yours, fortunately. Using browser entension, it should be possible but this is not what you are looking for here.